# Pass data from ajax call inside a view to a modal

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi i have a view that has an ajax script with it. They are all within one view. when the ajax call is success it will return a objects and open a modal. how can i pass the objects to the modal?

```
    <script>
    function PassFormToController() {
        debugger

        var orderNumber = document.getElementById('txtOrderNumber').value;
        var billingPostalCode = document.getElementById('txtBillingNumberPostalCode').value; 

        var url = "/LoginOrderStatus/ModalOrder";

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: url,
                data: { 'orderNumber': orderNumber, 'billingPostalCode': billingPostalCode },
                success: function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    debugger

                    var jdata = JSON.parse(data);             
                    var orderDetailOtherHeader = jdata.odrDetailOtherHdr; //dataToPass
                    var orderDetailHeader = jdata.odrDetailHdr;  //dataToPass
                    var itemList = jdata.odrProductList;  //dataToPass
                    var billingPostalcode = jdata.billingPostalCode;  //dataToPass

                    $("#loginOrderStatusModal").modal('show'); //pass here
                },
                error: function () {
                    debugger
                    alert("failed");
                }
            });        
    }
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Is your loginOrderStatusModal in the same page

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman yes

Comment: please share your html/view also

Comment: Here's what I would do. `POST` the data to the controller. Have that method return a `PartialView`. Access the data/ do whatever you with it in there. In the success of the `ajax`, all you will need to do is show the partial view/ modal

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="loginOrderStatusModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true" data-url=''>
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-title"></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

then:

```
            var jdata = JSON.parse(data);             
            var orderDetailOtherHeader = jdata.odrDetailOtherHdr; //dataToPass
            var orderDetailHeader = jdata.odrDetailHdr;  //dataToPass
            var itemList = jdata.odrProductList;  //dataToPass
            var billingPostalcode = jdata.billingPostalCode;  //dataToPass

            $('#modal-title').text(orderDetailOtherHeader);
            $('#modal-body').text(itemList)
            //plus your other variables

            $("#loginOrderStatusModal").modal('show'); //pass here
```

Comment: It  didnt work. it says [object Object]. what i am passing are objects if it helps.

Comment: You must build string from your object and pass it to modal content. I am not sure how your model looks like, so this is just example. You can also pass your model to Razor partial view and render it from call inside modal dialog.